# Launchpad MSP430 incremental blink with button

Tags: led, msp430, button, blink, energia

I'm new with this. I'm trying to make an incremental blinking LED with every time that I push the button, I'm using Energia and Launchpad MSP430, I don't know if somebody can give a example code to do this?

Comment: We don't has teh codez [sic].

Comment: @NickAlexeev - While I do agree this is *not* the proper forum for requests like this, I do think having simple examples for getting started **is** invaluable, particularly when using a new platform. If the question was for anything more complex then just blinking a LED and reading a button, I'd be inclined to dismiss it as someone trying to shirk work, but for the real basics, it's still nice to have something to work from. The initial bringup (e.g. set up clocks, jump to the right place, etc...) is often the hardest, since there is little feedback to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Please show some additional effort and tell us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Energia has great tutorials at http://energia.nu/Guide_index.html

Mainly the Button Tutorial (use a pushbutton to control an LED.)

And the Button State Change Tutorial (counting the number of button pushes.)

A little modification of both will give you what you need.